# css appearance can not be displayed web browser

Tags: asp.net, css

I attached css file following code my web site.I can display css style visual studio design time on my web page but when i run web project css style can not displayed.I use expolerer 8, and firefox 13.0.Also I can display css style my other web site project.What I forgot this web site? Thanks.

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Themes/default.css" type="text/css"  />
```

Comment: try this href="/Themes/default.css"

Comment: Are you sure your css path is right? Can you open that css file by pasting in the generated `href` value in your browser?

Comment: krish, I tryed bu it didn't work.

Comment: Niklas, I am sure already I can display css style design time and I select css file with pick url window.

Comment: may be any cache issue try ctrl+f5 on your browser

Comment: show us which area you added your stylesheet link

Comment: krish unfortunately I have tried

Comment: <head runat="server"> <title></title> <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server"> </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> <link rel="Stylesheet" href="Themes/default.css"type="text/css" /> </head>

Comment: everything seems correct in your code

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy helper in .net that will work out any path issues you may be having:

```
<link href="<%=Url.Content("~/Themes/default.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" 
  type="text/css" />
```

If you are not sure whether it is working, substitute your css file for something really simple:

```
body { background-color: Aqua; }
```

This will help to check whether the problem is:

- The stylesheet isn't referenced

Or

- The stylesheet is referenced, but is perhaps invalid / isn't doing what you expect